# drawImage not drawing image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage

I am new to HTML5 so please forgive my ignorance.
I am just trying to draw an image on a canvas, the code runs without any errors but the image is not drawn.

Following is the HTML and JS.

```js
var image
var canvas;
var context; 
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
window.onload = function(){
  canvas=  document.getElementById("canvas");
  context=canvas.getContext("2d"); 
  canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  canvasHeight = canvas.height; 
  image = document.createElement("img");
  image.onload = function(){ rotate(); } ;
  image.src = "images/roller.png";
}

function rotate() {
  // Clear the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
 
  // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
  context.translate(canvasWidth/2, canvasWidth/2);
 
  // Rotate 1 degree
  context.rotate(Math.PI / 180);
    
  // Move registration point back to the top left corner of canvas
  context.translate(-canvasWidth/2, -canvasWidth/2);
 
  context.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; height:400px; width:900px; overflow:hidden;">
<canvas id="canvas" style="margin:0 auto; width:900px; height:auto" align="center"></canvas>
<div style="height:30px; width:50px; position:relative; margin-top:-30%"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: I managed to get something to work in jsfiddle, but it crashes almost immediately. It's like a spirograph, yes?

Comment: I am trying to draw a spinning or rotating image, I will be adding this `setInterval(rotate, 1000);` line of code to the end `rotate()` function

Comment: Add support for image.onerror to see if there are image loading errors (f.ex. wrong path, caps, data...).

Comment: It could be that you're rotating the image to outside the canvas. Try a smaller angle and you'll probably see the image. See here http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/ for more info on how to properly rotate an image with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you should try:

You shouldn't set the canvas size in CSS, it'll mess everything up. Instead declare the size of the canvas, inside the JS code:

```
canvas.width = 900;
canvas.height = 400; //note that you can't set the canvas height to auto.
canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvasHeight = canvas.height;
```

2 Move your image to the center or else it will disappear

3 Remake your rotate function to include save() and restore() of your canvas, like so:

```
function rotate() {
  // Clear the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  //Save the canvas
  context.save();

  // Move registration point to the center of the canvas
  context.translate(canvasWidth/2, canvasWidth/2);

  // Rotate 1 degree
  context.rotate(Math.PI / 180);

  //Draw the image so that it appears rotated. Rotation at the center of the image.
  context.drawImage(image,canvasWidth/2-image.width/2, canvasWidth/2-image.height/2);
  // Restore the canvas 
 context.restore();
}
```